# How to check the status of carte de sejour Application?

Tags: resident-permit, france, legal, application-status

I have applied for Resident card after getting Recepisse and its been 2months already. I haven't got any response from the prefecture too. Is there any way to check the status online?

Comment: hello I had apply the cart sejour last two months ago, but i dont have any information, because this my first time to apply the cart sejour,

Answer (score 1):

Not in France. There are three ways you could try to find out (and even then they might not give you any information): call, email or go back in person.

You would normally get a text message when the card is ready.

Two months is still relatively short. Getting the card could take anywhere between 3-12 months (I’ve even heard of longer times), depending on the type of card requested, how backed up your prefecture is in terms of applications (each one is different), etc.

(This isn’t based on anything official but only on my own personal experience and experiences of others online).